# Progress bars use the same value

Tags: java, loops, progress-bar

I have two progressbars in one class. The problem is that the first and second update with the same integer so they display the same.

How I access the bar for the first one:

```
int percentDone = (int) ((i * 100.0) / numRows);
                        System.out.println(percentDone);
                        String PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME = UploadGUIBackup.PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME;
                        firePropertyChange(PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME, 0, percentDone);
```

Second

```
int percentDone = (int) ((j * 100.0) / numRows);
                        System.out.println("ESA : " + percentDone);     
                        String PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME2 = UploadGUIBackup.PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME2;
                        firePropertyChange(PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME2, 0, percentDone);
```

And finally here is how I set the from the other class:

```
            read.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

                    if (PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });

            read.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt2) {

                    if (PROGRESS_PROPERTY_NAME2.equals(evt2.getPropertyName())) {
                        progressBar2.setValue((Integer) evt2.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Why do they set the same integer? Did I handle the listeners wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you are currently using a `PropertyChangeListener` on the same `read`. So both progress bars will receive the same events, and thus update to the same integer values. Shouldn't it be `read1` and `read2` just like `progressBar1` and `progressBar2`?

Comment: When I did this it used the first bar and didn't use the second. Once it reached 100% it set it to 0% and started again.